# Giving Offset To Horizontally Centered Element Programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have set constraints on Storyboard, and tried to center CollectionView horizontally and give an extra offset.

[image]

I tried logging constraints on console by using this and consoled all the constraints.

```
print(collectionView.constraints)
```

---

How can I overwrite 30 offset to 50 offset (for example) programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `IBOutlet` to the constraint you wish to overwrite.

`@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewCenterXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

then whenever you want to change it.

`collectionViewCenterXConstraint.constant = 50` // the offset will be 50 now.

Comment: It's not very well documented (I feel) that you can have IBOutlets to NSLayoutConstraints, it's extremely useful.